# live debug in vm - failed to power on the virtual machine

Tags: visual-studio, remote-debugging, vmware-workstation

I want to do *remotely debug* my visual-cpp app with `VMWare Virtual Debugger` from a `Windows 7 x64` host in a `Windows Vista Ultimate x64` guest. I have the same `Visual Studio 2010` installed on both host and guest. I followed directions from [here](http://kristofmattei.be/2010/01/20/debugging-applications-in-virtual-machines-with-vmware-workstation-7-and-visual-studio-2008-sp1-2/), setting the following in the host VS VMWare options:

- virtual machine - path to `.vmx` file
- remote debug monitor path - path to `msvsmon.exe` on host
- remote debug monitor name - `VMDebug`
- guest command - `\\vmware-host\Shared Folders\...\bin\DebugWin32\MyApp.exe`
- guest login credentials - user and pass for vm

The problem is that when I start the remote debugging, I get:

> Debugging started...
>
> Starting the virtual machine.
>
> An error has occurred in the application. For more information please see the log file.  Its path is listed in the About box.
>
> VMware: Failed to power on the virtual machine. Unknown error.
>
> This action terminated prematurely or was canceled by user.
>
> An error has occurred in the application. For more information please see the log file.  Its path is listed in the About box.

I looked into the log file `ActivityLog.xml`, but I can only see `Information` records, and the only one in reference to VMWare is

> 303
>       2014/09/11 09:10:37.424
>       Information
>       VisualStudio
>       Unloading AddIn and calling OnDisConnection: VMDebugger.Connect

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong to debug remotely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got past this problem using [no authentication](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EEp6VqUg2WE) on the remote debugger from the guest. In addition to the steps shown in the tutorial, I replicated the solution path I had on the host in the guest for the application.